# MySQL: Show aggregate dues based on, since how many days past bill date

Tags: mysql, case

**What I am trying to achieve?**
[Expected Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmln8.png)
**Explaination:**To get overview of how much amount is due since the bill date is past. Here 0-15 means 15 days since bill date has passed, 16-30 means 16 to 30 days since bill date has passed & I want to know how much amount is due in these ranges and grand total at the end.

**No. of tables involved:**1
**Table:**User table
**Relevant Columns:**
bill_date
pending_amount

**Query I used:**

```
SELECT (CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15 THEN '0-15'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN '16-30'  
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 31 AND 45 THEN '31-45'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 46 AND 60 THEN '46-60'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '61-90'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN '91-180' 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 181 AND 365 THEN '181-365'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) >= 366 THEN '> 365
            END
        ) as bill_range,
        SUM(pending_amount) as amount_due,
FROM 
    `user`
    GROUP BY bill_range
```

**Result I got:**
[Current result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xokPr.png)

**How to achieve the result?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CASE statement creates only 1 column.
You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `0-15`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `16-30`,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 31 AND 45 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `31-45`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 46 AND 60 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `46-60`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `61-90`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `91-180`, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) BETWEEN 181 AND 365 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `181-365`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), bill_date) >= 366 THEN pending_amount ELSE 0 END) `> 365`,
  SUM(pending_amount) `grand total`
FROM `user`
```